# Declaring types in Go for a sample gonum application

Tags: go, gonum

Being an ardent fan of numpy, I was pleased to discover that a library for golang was in progress. I wrote a small test program, based heavily on the documentation, that looks like the following:

```
package main

import (

    "fmt"
    "math"
    "gonum.org/v1/gonum/stat"
)

func main() {

    xs := []float64 {

        23.32, 44.32, 100.12, 191.90,
        23.22, 90.21, 12.22, 191.21,
        1.21, 12.21, 34.23, 91.02,
    }

    variance := stat.Variance(xs)
    fmt.Printf("Data: %v\n", xs)

    stddev := math.Sqrt(variance)

    fmt.Printf("Standard deviation: %d\n\n", stddev)
}
```

When I attempted to build the program, I noticed the following compiler error:

```
C:\>go build hello.go
# command-line-arguments
.hello.go:19:30: not enough arguments in call to stat.Variance
        have ([]float64)
        want ([]float64, []float64)
```

Any advice would be most appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stat.Variance` expects two parameters of type `[]float64` of the same length:

```
func Variance(x, weights []float64) float64
```

You are missing the `weights` parameter. 
You can pass `nil` as the second parameter of `stat.Variance` function if you wants to set all the weights of the random variables to 1.

[stat Package Documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/gonum/stat#Variance)